# How to write ratio function in excel such that total sum is 100?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have to find ratio between two columns in excel.

I am using this function

```
 =num1/GCD(num1,num2)&":"&num2/GCD(num1,num2)
```

For the numbers :

```
X1 X2 Ratio Expected Ratio
20 80 1:4 20:80
17 34 1:2 33:67  
31 29 31:29 52:48
```

How to write ratio function in excel such that total sum is 100 and i achievethe expexted ratio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

`x1 + x2` represent `100%` so you just need to find out how much each value is in %.

Let's take the second example: 

`x1=17, x2=34
x1+x2=51
51......100%
17......x%
=> x=(17*100)/51=33.333`

To find out how much `51` is in % just subtract `100-33.33`

Comment: From you answer, 
=ROUND(num1/(num1+num2)*100)&":"&ROUND(num2/(num1+num2)*100). It works.